# locate and updatedb do nothing in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, locate, updatedb

I run Linux Mint 21.

Currently the `locate` command always returns no results, and   `updatedb` always returns immediately. The database   is sized no more than  a few kilobytes.

I have verified that the package `mlocate` is installed. The `updatedb` command is a cascading symbolic link that ultimately resolves to `/usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate`, a native binary executable.

The problem appears on two separate systems  having no particular commonality other than both being x86 64-bit machines running the same distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After investigation, I discovered the following option:

```
sudo updatedb --debug-pruning
```

The output is lengthy, but ends with the following line:

```
Skipping `/': bind mount
```

In fact, the root file system is a subvolume on a Btrfs partition.

Apparently, `plocate`, as well as `mlocate`, not playing well with Btrfs subvolumes is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=906591).